# Intersection of CFL and DCFL

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

Is **CFL $\cap$ DCFL = CFL**, always true?

CFL  - Any Context Free Language

DCFL - Any Deterministic Context Free Language

Comment: Your notation is off. $\mathrm{CFL} \cap \mathrm{DCFL}$ would denote the class of languages which are both context-free and deterministic context free.

Answer (score 2):

Even the intersection of two deterministic context-free languages may not be context-free.

Consider $L_1 = \{a^nb^nc^m\mid n,m\geqslant 0\}$ and $L_2 = \{a^nb^mc^m\mid n,m\geqslant 0\}$. Both languages are DCFL, but their intersection is $\{a^nb^nc^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$ which is not context-free.